# Data transparation in Query

Tags: oracle11g

I have the following code:

```
SELECT  
PPG.DESCRIPTION || ' ' || '(' || PPG.PERSONGROUP || ')' AS "Group",
PRS.DISPLAYNAME AS "Employee",
CASE PGT.ISCOORDINATOR
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'No'
END AS "Coordinator"
FROM PERSONGROUPTEAM PGT
  INNER JOIN PERSON PRS ON PRS.PERSONID= PGT.RESPPARTYGROUP
  INNER JOIN PERSONGROUP PPG on PPG.PERSONGROUP = PGT.PERSONGROUP
WHERE 
PPG.sogl=0
ORDER BY PPG.PERSONGROUP;
```

Which returns the following resault:

```
Group | Employee | Coordinator
-------------------------------
ABC   |John      | Yes
-------------------------------
ABC   |Ann       | No
-------------------------------
ABD   |Gimley    | No 
-------------------------------
```

I need to reverse output to get:

```
ABC
John   | Yes
Ann    | No
ABD
Gimley | No
```

How can I do it? Pivot? Or other way? Will be greatfull for any advise.

Comment: That looks like display/report formatting your client or application should be dealing with. Where and how are you running your query, and what (if anything) is consuming the results?

Comment: I need just to copy data in Excel. So it's not Oracle job?

Comment: Pivot table in Excel can solve my task, but really thought it can be done in Oracle.